# Can't build my application with Parse Crash Report when minifyEnabled is true

Tags: android, parse-platform, gradle, crash-reports

I'm trying to build an application. But it failed in Release when I set the minifyEnabled to true. Here is the error message:

> :app:parseUploadSymbolsRelease FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:parseUploadSymbolsRelease'.
>   android/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt (No such file or directory)

My build.grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'mykey'
            keyPassword 'mypass'
            storeFile file('keystore')
            storePassword 'mypass'
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'file:////Users/Shared/Mylib/AarRepository' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.8.3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.company.library:company-library:1.0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}

// to enable auto load of symbol file for crash report
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.parse'

parse {
    applicationId "myappid"
    masterKey "mymasterkey"

    uploadSymbols = ['release']
    retries 3
}
```

How to solve this? Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: have you configured proguard? `-keep class com.parse.** { *; }`

Comment: Yes, I have this. But doesn't work. Actually I have:
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }